# Leverage README.md content for module documentation

Tags: julia

I've written a nice README.md for my julia-lang package and I'd like to leverage it for the module documentation. Rather then copy/paste the content, I'd prefer to load and re-use the readme.md content instead, and maintain it only once. Is that possible with Julia documentation system?

thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

```
@doc read(joinpath(dirname(@__DIR__), "README.md"), String) MyPackage
```

Source: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/fun-one-liners/28352/57?u=findmyway

And then you can use it anywhere you want within a [@docs](https://juliadocs.github.io/Documenter.jl/stable/man/syntax/#@docs-block) block in the docs.

But do note that the syntax of Github README differs slightly from the one used in Julia docs.